# Set log group retention policy to never expire via clouformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Can I set a log group retention policy to 'never expire' using cloudformation ? F.e. I have the following template :

```
CustomLogGroup:
        Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
        Properties:
          LogGroupName: "logs"
          RetentionInDays: 3653
```

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html) suggests I should use a **DeleteRetentionPolicy** action . Can I define/perform this action using a yml template ? If yes , how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your logs to expire, then remove the `RetentionInDays` property altogether:

```
CustomLogGroup:
        Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
        Properties:
          LogGroupName: "logs"
```

the default retention will in fact be "Never expire".

The *DeleteRetentionPolicy* action seems to be something you can run after the log group is created to remove whatever retention policy the log group has.

Comment: What if I remove it after I create the log group, and then redeploy the stack?

Comment: @gshpychka remove what?

Comment: The `RetentionInDays` property.

Comment: @gshpychka CloudFormation should detect that there has been a change, and will run a stack update to change the setting

Comment: Right, but cloudformation cannot remove the log retention property from a log group, as stated in your answer, so what would be the result of that?

Comment: @gshpychka `cloudformation cannot remove the log retention property from a log group` where does my answer state that?

Comment: `where does my answer state that?` Here:
`The DeleteRetentionPolicy action seems to be something you can run after the log group is created to remove whatever retention policy the log group has.`

Comment: @gshpychka Right, and how does that contradict my previous statement?

Comment: Cloudformation cannnot unset a retention property on a log group, according to the docs, as that requires a separate API call. So I'm asking what will happen if I redeploy the stack without the property, after first deploying it with it.